# Travelling to London from US with an F1 Visa for vacation

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, f1-visas

Hi I am an Indian with a valid passport and am currently pursuing my graduate studies at the United States and I hold an F1 visa.

For my summer vacation I plan to visit my cousins in London for a two month stay there.

However, I am not sure as to what is the procedure for an Indian F1 student to obtain a tourist visa to the UK from the US. Can you please guide me on this?

Answer (score 4):

It should just be a normal tourist visa process. http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/visiting/general/requirements/

You need to book an appointment with the UK embassy in the US (not sure which city you're in right now). If you're visiting your family, you need to get a letter from your family in London to invite you with their details such as passport and means of support.